# exec format error

Tags: go

I recently installed lubuntu 11.04 on my pc. Following [this guide](http://golang.org/doc/install/source) on installing go from source, installing golang on my pc went well. To test my installation, I ran hello.go and got this error:

```
fork/exec /tmp/go-build748212890/command-line-arguments/_obj/a.out: exec format error
```

I looked it up on google, and one of the more relevant results that I found said to remove the package, then reinstall again. That did not help.

Can you tell me what is causing this error, and how I can fix this?

Thanks, and have a nice day!

Comment: How did you ran hello.go ? Using `go run` ?

Comment: Please add the output of `go env` and `env | grep GO` and maybe a `uname -a`

Comment: I ran hello go with "go run hello.go"

Comment: After 24-hours, I couldn't find a workaround. I decided to replace lubuntu with archbang. Golang works now.

Comment: Why 11.04 rather than 12.04 LTS or 12.10?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14943917/go-fork-exec-permission-denied-error

Answer (score 20):

I had this problem - it was very simple: I had set $GOOS to something other than the OS I was testing on. You can't do cross-platform testing. So for "go test", don't set $GOOS. I'm pretty sure the "Exec format error" you got was a result of go test trying to execute something on the wrong architecture/OS.

Comment: For me, removing `GOARCH` did the trick, inspired by your answer of course

Answer (score 0):

got this error on windows from Goland. The issue was that the test cases were nested and had pretty lengthy names which meant that the resultant binary had a file path with a super long name. Windows has a max file path limit of 260 characters and the total length of the file path to the binary exceeded that limit hence the error.
e.g

```
t.Run("Authentication Tests", func(t *testing.T) {
    t.Run("Given my conditions, when the function xyz is called, we expect this super 
           important result", func(t *testing.T) {

         })
})
```

The solution was to use fewer words in the test case names

Comment: FWIW, in Win10 it's possible to remove the 260 chars path limit. See https://www.howtogeek.com/266621/how-to-make-windows-10-accept-file-paths-over-260-characters/

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick for me.

```
export GOARCH="amd64"
```

https://github.com/golang/go/issues/53116