# Go fork/exec permission denied error

Tags: go

I recently installed Go onto our server with CentOS 6.3.  The install appears to have gone fine.  However I made a test "hello world" script, and when I run I get the following output.

```
fork/exec /tmp/go-build967564990/command-line-arguments/_obj/a.out: permission denied
```

Now running go env or other go commands seem to work.  At first I figured it was a permission issue, however running as root user I get the same thing.  An

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just guessing: Your nix perhaps disables for security reasons executing programs in /tmp. It might be configurable in CentOS, but I don't know that.

The alternative solution: It seems you're trying `go run` to execute a Go program (which is as script as C is a script). Try (assuming `$GOPATH=~`, the easy possibility) instead a normal build, i.e. instead of

```
me:~/src/foo$ go run main.go
```

try

```
me:~/src/foo$ go build # main.go should not be necessary here
me:~/src/foo$ ./foo
```

This approach will still use /tmp-whatever to create the binary, IIRC, but it will not attempt to execute it from there.

PS: *Do not* run these command as root. No need for that with correct setup.

Comment: @user387049, looks like jnml is correct: try running `mount` and see if the output for `/tmp` mentions the `noexec` option.

Comment: running mount did show that /tmp had the noexec option.  Not wanting to disable it, building and then running fixed the issue.  Thanks!

Comment: I made a quick Go script that does go build and then execs the program after. I prefer reducing two steps into one:) https://github.com/rjbishop/gobe

Answer (score 26):

I encountered this issue today but the solutions above did not work. Mine was fixed by simply running:

```
$ export TMPDIR=~/tmp/
```

then I was able to get the script to run with:

```
$ go run hello.go
hello, world
```

The only downside is you have to run `export TMPDIR` every time you want to run an application.

Kudos to [Adam Goforth](http://definingterms.com/2012/07/25/go-tools-with-tmpfs/)

Comment: you don't need to export every time you want to run.. just put the export on your ~/.profile or ~/.bashrc

Comment: if you want to avoid affecting other programs, you can `alias go='TMPDIR=~/tmp go'`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of settings `TMPDIR` which might affect other programs, you can [set `GOTMPDIR`](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/8451#issuecomment-341178968):

```
mkdir /some/where/gotmp
export GOTMPDIR=/some/where/gotmp
```

Then add `export GOTMPDIR=/some/where/gotmp` to your profile (i.e. `.bash_profile`) to make the variable permanent.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Fedora 31 and got a similar error which brought me here. I could not run the Go debugger used by Jetbrains IntelliJ Ultimate/GoLand without `fork/exec` & `permission denied` error. The solution was this:

```
setsebool deny_ptrace 0
```

See https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/SELinuxDenyPtrace for details.

Answer (score 0):

exec.Command return this sturct: type Cmd

standard comment：

```golang
// Dir specifies the working directory of the command.  
// If Dir is the empty string, Run runs the command in the
// calling process's current directory.
Dir string
```

so resolve, you can pass the exec cmd's path to exec yourself command:

```golang
cmd := exec.Command(xxxxx)
cmd.Dir = xxxxPath
```

and then you can call Run() or other Output() func

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my GOTMPDIR was already set, but TMPDIR wasnt.
So in order to solve this just set the TMPDIR:

```
export TMPDIR=/tmp
```

Save after restart

```
echo 'export TMPDIR=/tmp' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score -2):

To [fix this issue on my Chromebook](http://blog.dantup.com/2016/05/go-on-a-chromebook-without-linux/) I just remounted `/tmp` as executable. There may be security implications in doing this, but since `go run` works on other platforms I figure maybe it's not that bad (especially on a local dev machine):

```
sudo mount -i -o remount,exec /tmp/
```

I added this to my `.bash_profile` script.

Answer (score -4):

Consider trying:

```
sudo mount -o remount exec /tmp
```