# Go build: cgo fork/exec permission denied error

Tags: go, cgo

With a Go command like:

```
$ go build -mod=vendor -ldflags="-X github.com/openshift/odo/pkg/version.GITCOMMIT=40a90e175" cmd/odo/odo.go
```

I'm getting an error like:

```
# runtime/cgo
fork/exec /c: permission denied
```

but none of the solutions mention TMPDIR in  [Go fork/exec permission denied error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14943917/go-fork-exec-permission-denied-error) seem to work?

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had environment variable `CC` exported, set to `/c` without realizing it was a special variable to [cgo](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/).

Unsetting the `CC` variable solved my problem:

```
unset CC
```