# Makefile environment variable for specific target

Tags: go, makefile

I'm working on a go project which has a Makefile like below. Note that the "release" target sets two environment variables so that the "build" target cross-compiles for a specific architecture (which is possibly not that of the build system).

```make
# Generates a container release artifact.
release: export GOOS=linux
release: export GOARCH=amd64
release: build
  docker build ...

# Generates an executable for local use.
build: test
  go build ...

test: fmt vet
  go test ./...

...
```

The problems is that the `GOOS` and `GOARCH` env vars are also detected by the "go test" command which causes that step to fail since [cross-platform testing apparently is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44146306/244128).

To put it another way, it's like I want to clear the env vars for the "test" target, but the example below doesn't appear to unset the vars as expected:

```
unexport GOOS
unexport GOARCH
test: fmt vet
    go test ./...
```

I could remove the "test" dependency for the "build" target and it works fine but that seems like the wrong approach since I wouldn't want to build or release the binary if the tests fail.

Can I somehow modify the Makefile so that the `GOOS` and `GOARCH` environment variables are set by the "release" target and used by the "build" target but not the dependent "test" target?

Is there perhaps some other way to cross compile for release and still run the tests as a dependency without otherwise complicating things (such as building via Docker, etc)?  Note that the make targets are a bit more complicated than the example above due to several flags for the release and build targets.

Comment: go uses the same source code for all os'es so you can just make 1 test file and use that for every os

Comment: you could move your release build and test into docker, run it inside the container

Comment: @MadWombat sure but I don't want to repeat the makefile code for both local and docker builds (there's a lot more to it than shown in the minimal example in the question).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
test: export GOOS=
test: export GOARCH=
test: fmt vet
    go test ./...
```

Comment: Yes, this works great and probably reads a bit better than my solution. Ultimately this is the proper fix since testing can only be done on the local platform, so those env vars should never be set for the test target. Nit: spelling text/test

Answer (score 2):

Why not do something like this? It will just set those environment variables during that `go` execution.

```
    # Generates a container release artifact.
release: build
  docker build ...

# Generates an executable for local use.
build: test
  GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build ...

test: fmt vet
  go test ./...

...
```

Comment: Because I also want to build the executable for use on my local system. So "build" should only cross-compile when it's invoked via "release".

Comment: Ahhh... makes total sense. In that case you have two options. a. put the environment variable definitions inside of the Dockerfile or b. write an if statement inside of the Makefile that runs two different `go build ...`

Comment: Or c. write another Makefile targer that is run by `release`, separate from the one you run locally. Don't over engineer. :)

Comment: Ah wait - your observation about setting env vars on the command line has inspired the answer, I can just unset them on the "test" command so it uses the local system os/arch!

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that I can unset the env vars in the troublesome test command itself:

```
test: fmt vet
    GOOS= GOARCH= go test ./...
```

This way the "go test" command will always use the local system OS and architecture (as it should!).

Thx @KonstantinItskov for the inspiration